# Refesh ViewData after call Jquery function MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to refresh the items of two ListBox after a dropdownlist value change.
The data of the ListBoxes is in the ViewData and i call a action controller from jquery function, but the ViewData after the call have the same data.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        $('#users').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $('#users').val();
            $.post('@Url.Action("GruposUsuario", "Grupos")', { usersId: selectedValue }, function () {
                var gruposAsig = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["gruposAsignados"]))');
                var gruposDisp = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["gruposDisponibles"]))');
                $('#gruposAsignados').empty();
                $('#gruposAsignados').addItems(gruposAsig);
                $('#gruposDisponibles').empty();
                $('#gruposDisponibles').addItems(gruposDisp);
            });
        });
        $.fn.addItems = function (grupos) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var list = this;

                $.each(grupos, function (index, itemData) {
                    var option = new Option(itemData.Text, itemData.Value);
                    list.add(option);
                });
            });
        };


    });
```

And the Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GruposUsuario(string usersId)
        {
            AllUsers();
            GruposAsignados(int.Parse(usersId));
            //GruposDispobibles(int.Parse(usersId));
            return Json("Usuario");
        }


        void GruposAsignados(int usersId)
        {            
            var grupos  = new BL.Grupos().GruposAsignados(usersId);
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var grupo in grupos)
            {
                SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = grupo.GroupName,
                    Value = grupo.GroupsId.ToString()
                };
                list.Add(selectList);
            }
            ViewData["gruposAsignados"] = list as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
        }
```

How can i refesh the ViewDatas after the event?

Comment: Please note that the [tag:model-view-controller] tag is intended for questions about the *pattern*, whereas your question concerns the ASP.NET-specific implementation, for which you should use the [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor code is parsed on the server before it is sent to the view. Your use of `@Html.Raw(...)` assigns vales to `gruposAsig` and `gruposDisp` that are the initial values of the `ViewData` properties (inspect the source when you first render the page).

In any case you method `GruposAsignados()` only returns a string with the value `"Usuario"`. If you want to return json data to update the options in two dropdownlists, then you controller method should be

```
[HttpGet] // its a GET
public ActionResult GruposUsuario(string usersId)
{
  var gruposAsignados= new BL.Grupos().GruposAsignados(usersId).Select(g => new
  {
    ID = g.grupo.GroupsId;
    Name = g.GroupName;
  }
  var gruposDisponibles = // another query
  return Json(new { Asignados = gruposAsignados, Disponibles = gruposDisponibles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then the script should be

```
var asignados = $('#gruposAsignados'); // cache it
var disponibles = $('#gruposDisponibles');
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GruposUsuario", "Grupos")', { usersId: selectedValue }, function (response) {
  if(response) {
    asignados.empty();
    // or asignados.empty().append($('</option>').val('').text('-Please select-'));
    $.each(response.Asignados, function(index, item) {
      asignados.append($('</option>').val(item.ID).text(item.Name));
    });
    disponibles.empty();
    $.each(response.Disponibles, function(index, item) {
      disponibles.append($('</option>').val(item.ID).text(item.Name));
    });
  }
});
```

Side note: There is no need to create `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. The browser has no knowledge of what a C# class is and you just returning extra unnecessary data (the values of the `Selected`, `Group` and `Disabled` properties) which are never used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Its work, but it no enter to the each loop, i check the data and it has values. what can i do for this?